# bash manipulate multiple strings in a file

Tags: string, bash, manipulate

I am looking to strip the below input lines from the filename and I am using this file:

```
cat <<EOF >./tz.txt
2019/12/_MG_0263.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2019/12/_MG_0262.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2020/06/ok/_MG_0003.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/06/ok/_MG_0002.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/04/_MG_0137.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/_MG_0136.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/_MG_0136.CR2.xmp:           bopt:keywordlist="red,car,2020"
EOF
```

and now I am using the below script (stored in file ab.sh) to just exclude the [filename.xmp: bopt:] (e.g. _MG_0263.CR2.xmp: bopt:) from each line so that the output looks like this:

```
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
```

Above is the complete expected output. Some folders may have different structures, like the one 2020/06/ok/

The script code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="./tz.txt"
while read line ; do
        # variable a generates the folter structure with a variable range of considered columns
        # using awk to figure out how many columns (aka folders) there are in the structure
        a=$( cut -d"/" -f 1-$( awk -F'/' '{ print NF-1 }' $line ) $line )
    #                       |                                   |
    #                       -this bit should create a number for- 
    #                       -the cut command                    -
    
    #   then b variable stores the last bit in the  string
        b=$( cut -d":" -f 3 $line )
    
    #   and below combine results from above variables 
        echo ${a} ${b}
    done < ${file}
```

In the attached image is an illustration of the logic used to split the string in columns and get only the relevant data.

The problem is that I get the below error and I am not sure where I’ve gone wrong.
Thank you for any suggestions or help

```
$ sh ~/ab.sh
awk: fatal: cannot open file `2019/12/_MG_0263.CR2.xmp:' for 

reading (No such file or directory)
cut: '2019/12/_MG_0263.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"': No such file or directory
cut: '2019/12/_MG_0263.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"': No such file or directory

awk: fatal: cannot open file `2019/12/_MG_0262.CR2.xmp:' for reading (No such file or directory)
cut: '2019/12/_MG_0262.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"': No such file or directory
cut: '2019/12/_MG_0262.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"': No such file or directory

awk: fatal: cannot open file `2020/06/ok/_MG_0003.CR2.xmp:' for reading (No such file or directory)
cut: '2020/06/ok/_MG_0003.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"': No such file or directory
cut: '2020/06/ok/_MG_0003.CR2.xmp:': No such file or directory
cut: 'bopt:keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"': No such file or directory

....
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. I am sorry for missing that, and it was quite relevant @markp-fuso . Now updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `awk` idea to replace the `while` loop:

```
awk -F':' '
{ gsub(/[^/]+$/,"",$1)     # strip everything after last "/" from 1st field
  print $1, $3
}' "${file}"

# or as a one-liner sans comments:

awk -F':' '{gsub(/[^/]+$/,"",$1); print $1, $3}' "${file}"
```

This generates:

```
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
```

---

One `sed` alternative:

```
$ sed -En 's|^(.*)/[^/]+:.*:([^:]+)$|\1/ \2|p' "${file}"
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable support for extended regexs, suppress automatic printing of input lines
- since data includes the `/` character we'll use `|` as the `sed` script delimiter
- `^(.*)/` - [1st capture group] match everything up to the last `/` before ...
- `[^/]+:` - matching everything that's not a `/` up to the 1st `:`, then ...
- `.*:` - match everything up to next `:`
- `([^:]+)$` - [2nd capture group] lastly match everything at end of line that is not `:`
- `\1/ \2` - print 1st capture group + `/` + 2nd capture group

This generates:

```
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2019/12/ keywordlist="pinhole,car,2019"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/06/ok/ keywordlist="lowkey,car,Chiaroscuro,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
2020/04/ keywordlist="red,car,2020"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the final parameter to the `awk` command should be a filename. You are passing it a variable containing the contents of one line of the input file. This is why you are getting the `awk: fatal: cannot open file` errors.

Secondly, you are making the same mistake with the `cut` command, resulting in the `: No such file or directory` errors.

Both `awk` and `cut` are designed to work on complete files. You can chain them together so that the output of one becomes the input of another by using the pipe character: `|`. For example:

```
cat ${file} | awk ... | cut ...
```

But this can quickly become complex and unwieldy. A better solution is to use the Stream Editor `sed`. `sed` will read it's input line by line and can perform quite complex operations on each line before outputting the result, line by line.

This should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/tz.txt"

sed -En 's/^([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/).*bopt:(.*)$/\1 \2/p' ${file}
```

Here is an explanation of the quoted expression:

`s/pat/rep/p`   Search for `pat` and if found, replace with `rep` and print the result.

In our case, `pat` is:

`^`          The beginning of a line

`(`          Start remembering what follows

`[0-9]{4}`   Any digit repeated exactly 4 times

`\/`         The `/` character (escaped)

`[0-9]{2}\/` Any digit repeated exactly 2 times, followed by `/`

`)`          Stop remembering

`.*bopt:`    any 0 or more characters followed by `bopt:`

`(.*)`       remember 0 or more characters...

`$`          ...up to the end of the line.

And `rep` is:

`\1 \2`         The first thing remembered, followed by a space, followed by the second thing we remembered.